# Redirection loop problem: old-style urls to new user-friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, loops, redirect

I'm tryin' to replace old-style urls to the new one user-friendly only using .htaccess

e.g. `domain.com/dir/?id=101 -> domain.com/dir/robots`

It should be accessed from old links `(?id=...)` by users or searchbots and redirected to the new one with 301 status code and of course it should be accessed from the new url.

my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir/

RewriteRule ^robots/?$ ?id=101 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=101$
RewriteRule ^$ robots? [R=301,L]
```

It returns redirection loop, obviously.

Unfortunately i can not modify CMS engine, so the only solution is to do this with .htaccess rules.

I've googled a lot but didn't found any working solution for this issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**SOLVED**

Ok, a little bit of random magic and i found solution:

```
RewriteRule ^robots/?$ ?id=101 [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=101$
RewriteRule ^$ robots? [R=301,L]
```

**Important:** No space after `!=200` in condition `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` . with  space it doesnt work.

Comment: For your 2nd rule (301 redirect) -- add one more condition: only redirect if URL was not yet rewritten -- check `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable (it should contain `GET /?id=101 HTTP/1.1` or something very similar). Now you know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir/

RewriteRule ^robots/?$ ?id=101 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/id=101$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/dir/robots? [R=301,L]
```